# How to allow a Lambda Function inside a VPC to Publish in the IoT-Core MQTT Broker outside the VPC in AWS?

Tags: aws-lambda, mqtt, serverless, amazon-vpc, aws-iot

**Scenario-1**: I have the follow architecture with the lambda that can listen to an event `(1)` in the MQTT broker (IoT-Core) and can retrieve the data and save it `(2)` in the **RDS**. The RDS and Lambda are both inside the same VPC. The problem here is that the lambda can't publish back `(3)` in the Broker the result of the transaction.

[image]

**Scenario-2**: I have the same lambda but it is outside of the RDS VPC. In this configuration the lambda can listen to an event `(1)` inside the MQTT broker (IoT-Core) and publish back `(3)`. The issue is that the lambda can't save data in the RDS `(2)`. 
[image]

I would like to allow the lambda to publish in the MQTT broker in the **Scenario-1**. In fact I don't know why it is possible to the lambda to be triggered by an event in the broker but not allowed to published back If the VPC where the reason it would not be possible to listen also.

How can I allow the lambda to publish back in the **Scenario-1**?
This is the configuration inside `serverless.yml`:

```
lambdaRSDInsert:
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-${self:custom.fnLambdaRSDInsert}
    handler: fnLambdaRSDInsert.fnLambdaRSDInsert
    events:
    - iot:
        name: ${self:custom.fnLambdaRSDInsert}
        sql: "SELECT *, topic() AS topic FROM 'company/sys/cmd/fnLambdaRSDInsert/#' "  
    memorySize: 256
    iamRoleStatementsName: ${self:provider.stage}-${self:custom.fnLambdaRSDInsert}-iamFnLambdaRSDInsert
    iamRoleStatements:
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
          - 'rds:*'
          Resource: 'arn:aws:rds:${self:provider.region}:xxxxxxx:db:${file(env.yml):rdsMySqlCluster-${self:provider.stage}}'
        - Effect: 'Allow'
          Action:
          - 'logs:CreateLogGroup'
          - 'logs:CreateLogStream'
          - 'logs:PutLogEvents'
          - 'ec2:CreateNetworkInterface'
          - 'ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces'
          - 'ec2:DeleteNetworkInterfaces'
          Resource: "*"
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - "iot:*"
          Resource: '*' 
    vpc: ${file(env.yml):vpc-${self:provider.stage}}
    environment:
      rdsMySqlDb: ${file(env.yml):rdsMySqlDb-${self:provider.stage}}
      rdsMySqlHost: ${file(env.yml):rdsMySqlHost-${self:provider.stage}}
      rdsMySqlUsername: ${file(env.yml):rdsMySqlUsername-${self:provider.stage}}
      rdsMySqlPassword: ${file(env.yml):rdsMySqlPassword-${self:provider.stage}}
      MQTT_ENDPOINT: '${file(env.yml):mqttEndPoint}${self:provider.region}.amazonaws.com'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your subnets to have internet access in the VPC dashboard by adding an Internet Gateway. The gateway needs to be added to the security groups where you can configure the allows IPs and Ports.

Afterwards you need to create an Elastic IP where you need to add the Network Interfaces that where created during the association of the subnets to the Lambda function (they can be found in EC2)

I followed this two guides:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html